# Ajax, Jquery in wordpress return nothing

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

this is my code, it works without wordpress. but as put into wordpress, the ajax part always failed. 
i include jquery and ajax in wordpress like this

```
function transtatus_metaboxes(){
    if (is_admin() && !trans_parents_zero($GLOBALS["post_info"])){
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js');
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        add_meta_box('transtatus_show', 'Translations Status', 'transtatus_show', 'post', 'side', 'high');      
    }
}

function trans_action_ajax(){
?><!-- jquery ajax function -->
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function() {
    $(".ovalbutton").click(function() {
        var val = $(this).attr('href').match(/p=([0-9]+)/)[1];
        var val_adi = $(this).attr('href').match(/id=([0-9]*)/)[1]; 
        var str_val = null;
        var fnl_val = null;
        var dataString = null;

        if(val == 1){
            str_val = "Require Translation"; 
        } else if(val == 2) {
            str_val = "On Progress";
        } else if(val == 3) {
            str_val = "Completed";
        } else {
            str_val = "Finialised";
        }

        fnl_val = str_val + "," + val_adi;
        dataString = 'trans_cont_value=' + fnl_val;         
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "http://localhost/marcopolowordpress/wp-content/plugins/translation-status/update.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $('#display').text(" status set to " + str_val);
            }  
        });
        alert(dataString);  
    });
});
//->
</script>
```

then this is the update.php

```
<?php
require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))."/wp-config.php");

$q=$_POST["trans_cont_value"];

$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$con){
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_query("set names ".DB_CHARSET); //solved the unwanted character
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con);

if(isset($q)){
    $strarray = explode(',', $q);
    $value = $strarray[0];
    $id = $strarray[1];

    mysql_query("UPDATE MESSAGES SET msg = '$value'");
}
?>
```

I dont see any problem with those code, but it doesnt work in wordpress. any help?
appreciate in advance

Comment: Did you mean to call a php file with the url "localhost" when running on wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your URL

```
url: "http://localhost/marcopolowordpress/wp-content/plugins/translation-status/update.php",

to 

url: "<?php get_bloginfo('wpurl');?>/wp-content/plugins/translation-status/update.php",
```